# What repository provides ksh for RedHat universal base image version 8 (ubi8)

Tags: rhel, rpm, ksh

Please tell me if RedHat provides a repo with the ksh RPM for their Universal Base Image version 8 (ubi8). The UBI images are great because they are pre-configured to fetch RPMs from many repos but don't require a RedHat network subscription.

I get a strange match on ksh in ubi7 -- it comes back with bash:

```
% docker run -it registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7:latest yum search ksh
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

ubi-7                                                                                                                                     | 3.8 kB  00:00:00     
ubi-7-rhah                                                                                                                                | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
ubi-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                                                  | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
ubi-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                                                | 3.8 kB  00:00:00     
ubi-server-rhscl-7-rpms                                                                                                                   | 3.8 kB  00:00:00     
(1/15): ubi-7/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                           |   92 B  00:00:00     
(2/15): ubi-7/x86_64/group                                                                                                                |  124 B  00:00:00     
(3/15): ubi-7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                           | 800 kB  00:00:00     
(4/15): ubi-7-rhah/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                      |   92 B  00:00:00     
(5/15): ubi-7-rhah/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                      | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
(6/15): ubi-7-rhah/x86_64/group                                                                                                           |  124 B  00:00:00     
(7/15): ubi-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                        |   92 B  00:00:00     
(8/15): ubi-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                        | 6.8 kB  00:00:00     
(9/15): ubi-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/group                                                                                             |  124 B  00:00:00     
(10/15): ubi-7-server-optional-rpms/x86_64/group                                                                                          |  124 B  00:00:00     
(11/15): ubi-7-server-optional-rpms/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                     |  14 kB  00:00:00     
(12/15): ubi-7-server-optional-rpms/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                     |   92 B  00:00:00     
(13/15): ubi-server-rhscl-7-rpms/x86_64/group                                                                                             |  124 B  00:00:00     
(14/15): ubi-server-rhscl-7-rpms/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                        |   92 B  00:00:00     
(15/15): ubi-server-rhscl-7-rpms/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                        | 396 kB  00:00:00     
========================================================================= Matched: ksh ==========================================================================
bash.x86_64 : The GNU Bourne Again shell
```

Here's the no-match situation in ubi8:

```
% docker run -it registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8:latest yum search ksh
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS                                                                                   4.3 MB/s | 786 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream                                                                                 11 MB/s | 2.4 MB     00:00    
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder                                                                        127 kB/s |  15 kB     00:00    
No matches found.
```

I'm ok with adding additional repositories during the docker build.  I already add the Fedora EPEL repository (installed via https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm) but ksh is not in there either.

From searching the interwebs I find file ksh-20120801-34.el7.x86_64.rpm at various sites, but I don't want to create a "frankenstein" system by mixing and matching Centos with RedHat RPMs.  And I'd really like to get this from an official source.

This feels like a silly noob question, such a basic tool as a linux shell is somehow difficult to find & install. Is there a chance that RedHat simply does not provide ksh for UBI at all?

Comment: Is adding the copr repo an option? You'd at least get something newer than what you found.

Comment: UBI editions are subsets of RHEL.  As far as I am aware, `ksh` is not included in those subsets.

Comment: I guess "Redhat CentOS 7" packages are more official than most 3rd party repo´s. Latest is `ksh-20120801-142.el7.x86_64.rpm` : 2020-04-03 http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/ . Please note the minor version = 142.

Comment: What's the copr repo? And thanks @KnudLarsen but I don't want to add CentOS RPMs to a (pure?) RedHat system.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/building_running_and_managing_containers/index#adding-software-to-a-running-ubi-container_building-running-and-managing-containers says "If you are running a UBI container on a registered and subscribed RHEL host, the main RHEL Server repository is enabled inside the standard UBI container, along with all the UBI repositories. So the full set of Red Hat packages is available. " - is that an option?

Comment: https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/x86_64/baseos/os/Packages/k/ indicates that ksh is not in the base UBI image.

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller I will work on getting the *host* server registered and subscribed, that never occurred to me.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the note from [6.1 Adding software to a running UBI container](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/building_running_and_managing_containers/index#adding-software-to-a-running-ubi-container_building-running-and-managing-containers):

> If you are running a UBI container on a registered and subscribed RHEL host, the main RHEL Server repository is enabled inside the standard UBI container, along with all the UBI repositories. So the full set of Red Hat packages is available. From the UBI minimal container, all UBI repositories are enabled by default, but no repositories are enabled from the host by default.

... and use the host's RHEL repository, which does have ksh available.

Comment: Jeff I checked and my UBI8 container is running on a registered & subscribed RHEL 7.4 system. The host can see ksh in a repo, but the guest container cannot. Probably the versions have to match exactly?

Comment: I don't have a similar setup at-hand, but I suspect you're correct in that they expect the host to be at RHEL8 as well.

Comment: I remain baffled how the dnf config files and dnf process in the UBI container can benefit from config files etc. on the host system. Isn't isolation the purpose of a container?

Comment: The Red Hat statement sounds to me like the main host's repo information is copied into the container, but disabled by default.

Comment: This link leads to a Red Hat login page.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't for me. Anyway, that's why I excerpted the important bit.